# Chrome Black search URL

Tags: google-chrome, search, url

How can I change the color of the search bar of Chrome?

[image: chrome black search bar]

Since I restart my PC, Chrome looks like that but I prefer previous state

Comment: did you try to reset the theme from chrome://settings/?search=theme ?

Comment: yes i tried it, but everything remains the same.

Comment: Did you try to reset the chrome? and have you ever tweaked Chrome registry?

Comment: Just had this issue appear on both my work and home computer, both set to light mode in settings. Also it appears to mirror the theme because when I change theme it follows the outer ring colour with a lighter hue effect, I tried about a dozen themes and was unable to find one that didn't follow this pattern, new update must have removed a customizable colour field for themes

Comment: Add me to the list of people with the same issue (today after updating from Chrome 80 to 81)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Windows 10 theme color is on '`Dark`'.

Head to Settings > Personalization > Colors and unselect '`Dark`' under '`Choose your default app mode`'.

[image: SCREENSHOT of Windows 10 settings page]